# Binary Coded Decimal Maths in embedded Java

Tags: java, embedded, bcd

I would like to use decimals represented in byte arrays (BCD format) to perform mathematical increments on the decimal values in the form of byte arrays.

An example is I would like to do `255 + 1` in maths which gives `256`. When done in a binary array format, the `255` value would be `00000000FF` and `1` is `0000000001` value in hexadecimal representation of bytes. The result to be expected would be `0000000100`.

My following code attempts to do a 5 byte array increment of `255` by `1`. My end results is `00000001FE` which the last byte `0xFE` is suppose to be `0x00`. How do I correct my algorithm to properly perform a 5 byte array increment by only using basic binary operands (the Java environment is embedded) ?

```
    private static byte[] clkCtrCurr = new byte[5];
    private static byte[] inc = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01};
    private static byte buff;
    private static byte carry;

    public static void binAdd() {
        buff = (byte) (clkCtrCurr[4] ^ inc[4]);
        carry = (byte) (clkCtrCurr[4] & inc[4]);
        clkCtrCurr[4] = buff;
        clkCtrCurr[3] ^= carry;
        buff = (byte) (clkCtrCurr[3] ^ inc[3]);
        carry = (byte) (clkCtrCurr[3] & inc[3]);
        clkCtrCurr[3] = buff;
        clkCtrCurr[2] ^= carry;
        buff = (byte) (clkCtrCurr[2] ^ inc[2]);
        carry = (byte) (clkCtrCurr[2] & inc[2]);
        clkCtrCurr[2] = buff;
        clkCtrCurr[1] ^= carry;
        buff = (byte) (clkCtrCurr[1] ^ inc[1]);
        carry = (byte) (clkCtrCurr[1] & inc[1]);
        clkCtrCurr[1] = buff;
        clkCtrCurr[0] ^= carry;
        clkCtrCurr[0] ^= inc[0];
    }
```

Comment: What is meant by "basic binary operands"?  Why don't we use + on the bytes, assign to an integer and work it out from there?

Comment: It is on an embedded Java system (JavaCard) that may or may not support Int. The most it supports is short which is 2 bytes and some counter like HOTP requires things like 4 to 8 bytes worth of decimals that are usually processed in the system as bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BCD format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) means that each decimal digit (0-9) is stored in 4 bits (or 8 if unpacked), which means that the number looks decimal when printed in hex.

Example: The decimal number `123` should be stored in BCD as `0x0123` (decimal 291).

If unpacked, it would simply be 3 bytes: `0x01 0x02 0x03` or `0x010203` (decimal 66051).

So, if you wanted a 5-byte packed big-endian BCD number, i.e. a 10-digit decimal number, and you want to increment, you could do this:

```
private static void increment(byte[] bcd) {
    for (int i = bcd.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        byte b = bcd[i];
        if ((b & 0x0F) < 0x09) {
            bcd[i] = (byte)(b + 1);
            return;
        }
        if ((b & 0xF0) < 0x90) {
            bcd[i] = (byte)((b & 0xF0) + 0x10);
            return;
        }
        bcd[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
private static void print(byte[] bcd) {
    for (int i = 0; i < bcd.length; i++) {
        if (i != 0)
            System.out.print(' ');
        System.out.printf("%02x", bcd[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] bcd1 = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x23 }; // decimal 123
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        increment(bcd1);
        print(bcd1);
    }
    byte[] bcd2 = { (byte)0x99, (byte)0x99, (byte)0x99, (byte)0x99, (byte)0x95 }; // decimal 9_999_999_995
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        increment(bcd2);
        print(bcd2);
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
00 00 00 01 24
00 00 00 01 25
00 00 00 01 26
00 00 00 01 27
00 00 00 01 28
00 00 00 01 29
00 00 00 01 30
00 00 00 01 31
00 00 00 01 32
00 00 00 01 33
99 99 99 99 96
99 99 99 99 97
99 99 99 99 98
99 99 99 99 99
00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 01
00 00 00 00 02
00 00 00 00 03
00 00 00 00 04
00 00 00 00 05
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
static byte add(byte x, byte y, byte[] result, byte index) {
    byte c = 0;
    while (y != 0) {
        byte t = (byte)(x & y);
        c |= t;
        x = (byte)(x ^ y);
        y = (byte)(t << 1);
    }
    result[index] = x;
    return (byte)((c & 0x80) != 0 ? 1 : 0);
}

static byte add(byte a, byte b, byte c, byte[] result, byte index) {
    byte carry = add(a, b, result, index);
    if (c > 0)
        carry |= add(result[index], c, result, index);
    return carry;
}

public static void add(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
    byte c = 0;
    c = add(a[4], b[4], c, a, (byte)4);
    c = add(a[3], b[3], c, a, (byte)3);
    c = add(a[2], b[2], c, a, (byte)2);
    c = add(a[1], b[1], c, a, (byte)1);
    c = add(a[0], b[0], c, a, (byte)0);
}
```